# How do I keep argparse from failing because it doesn't recognize the program name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm getting an error trying to run a some python code. The error I get is that argparse doesn't recognize an argument: the program name.

```
migration.py: error: unrecognized arguments: migration.py
```

The command I pass is ok I believe:

```
python migration.py --checkoutdir "C:\Projects\SomeDir\CodeFreeze_20131129" --publishonly
```

And for context, here is the argparse code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Branch/Publish')
parser.add_argument('-c','--checkoutdir', nargs=1, required=True, help="Directory to checkout branch into, or if it exists, the directory to publish from.")    
parser.add_argument('-b','--branchonly', nargs='?', const=True, help="Only create a branch. Checkout branch into --checkoutdir")
parser.add_argument('-p','--publishonly', nargs='?', const=True, help="Only publish from --checkoutdir.")
parser.add_argument('--publishdir', nargs=1, required=False, help="Directory to output publish files", default="C:\Publish")
parser.add_argument('-g','--configuration', nargs=1, required=False, help="Publish configuration to use.")
parser.add_argument('-s','--solutionfile', nargs=1, required=False, help="Solution file in --checkoutdir used for publishing.")
parser.add_argument('-t','--targetProj', nargs=1, required=False, help="Target project to publish. Replace '.' with '_' to make msbuild happy.")

args = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

I was under the impression that argparse would skip `sys.argv[0]` and use it as the program name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass in `argv` at all; if you don't pass in the `args` argument to `parser.parse_args()` it'll use `sys.argv[1:]`, **skipping** `argv[0]`:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

From the [`argparse` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/argparse.py#l1711):

```
def parse_known_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
    if args is None:
        # args default to the system args
        args = _sys.argv[1:]
```